# Fix a java.lang.NullPointerException error in a queue

Tags: java, pointers, queue

So I implemented a queue in Java and I was Trying to implement a procedure that inserts an element at the end of the queue.But I get an error message "java.lang.NullPointerException".I am new at this and I don't know what this means or how to fix it.

```
class Node {

public int ielement;
public String selement;
public Node next;




public Node(int iel, String sel) {

    ielement = iel;
    selement = sel;
}
class Implement {


private Node head;
private Node tail;

 public Implement() {
    head = null;
    tail=null;
}
public void InsertAtTheEnd(int iel, String sel){
    Node newNode=new Node(iel,sel);
    if(!Empty())//if the queue is empty{
    tail.next=newNode;
    tail=newNode;}
    else{
    newNode.next=head;
    head=newNode;
        }

}

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Implement k = new Implement();
   k.InsertAtTheEnd(1, "b");
   k.InsertAtTheEnd(3, "bes");
   k.InsertAtTheEnd(4, "kes");}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize `tail`. If the queue is not empty, `tail.next` should point to the newly created node, as you have done. If it is, though, both `head` and `tail` should just point to the newly added node.

```
public void insertAtTheEnd (int iel, String sel) {
    Node newNode = new Node(iel,sel);
    if (!empty()) {
        tail.next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    } else {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
}
```